# Do you have to stay at a hotel to get reservations at Sukiyabashi Jiro?

Tags: japan, tokyo, restaurants

From what I've read, you can only get reservations at [Sukiyabashi Jiro](https://www.sushi-jiro.jp/) by having your hotel book it for you a month in advance or so.

This seems odd to me, since this would exclude all native Japanese who actually live in Tokyo. Surely the hotel can't be *mandatory*.

It's a problem for me because I'm staying with a relative here, not at a hotel. What can I do?

Comment: A few years back, we tried to get reservations through the concierge at the Park Hyatt, and were told that they did not accept foreign visitors at all (or more precisely, people not speaking Japanese). It seems things have changed a bit, but given the very small size of the restaurant and its popularity, it must remain quite difficult to get a reservation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hotel concierge booking doesn't apply to local residents. It is for visitors. There's no mention of one month in advance in their [reservation notice](https://www.sushi-jiro.jp/%E6%9C%AC%E5%BA%97%E3%81%AE%E3%81%94%E4%BA%88%E7%B4%84%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/), but it is clear, both in the Japanese and English versions, that they don't accept reservations by phone.

Locals probably can get a booking by visiting the restaurant, or using a booking service. And I suspect [some] regulars will just need a phone call. With ten seats only, that restaurant can pick and choose its clients anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> What can I do?

Nothing. You will not get a reservation at Jiro's, forget it. You need to be extremely well-connected, rich or lucky (better yet, a combination thereof) to land one, even as a local.

If you are well connected, ask your connection to ask for you. If you are rich, stay at a very expensive hotel, and ask them to ask for you (if you have a credit card with a concierge service, that *could* also work). If you are feeling lucky, ask your Japanese relative to call the number on the homepage and pray that the call gets through, and if it does get through, pray again that they will talk to you.

***Update (November 2019)***: Sukiyabashi Jiro has been [kicked out of the Michelin guide](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/nov/26/too-exclusive-worlds-best-sushi-restaurant-stripped-of-its-three-michelin-stars) because the guide considers that it "does not accept reservations from the general public".

Comment: Not that I don’t believe you, but how do you know that it’s that difficult? Just from your experience talking to people?

Comment: @Aerovistae It's basically common knowledge; there are also plenty of blog posts about it if you care to search.